# Can I force cells in a uitableview not to start at index 0 in every section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static table view with 6 cells and 6 separators. I need cell 1 to have an index of 0 and cell 6 to finish with an index of 5, is this possible? My code below doesn't work due to the fact every cell is in a separate section, so it thinks cell 0 is selected every time, and it populates the cells with the same data as again, it thinks its cell 0.

```
-(void) longTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer= %@",gestureRecognizer);
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"longTap began");

        CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        if (indexPath == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);

            switch (indexPath.row)
            {
                case 0:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    del.tableRowNumber = 5;
                    break;
            }
        }

        UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MealPlannerRecipeTypeViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    RecipeInfo *recipeInfo = recipeInfoArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = recipeInfo.name;
    return cell;
}
```

I've just tried this to get the tag:

```
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:myTable];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"TAG IS : %i", cell.tag);
```

Every cell is still tagged with the value of the first cell in my table though?

Comment: You can give tag value to each cell, and on basis of tag you load your data.

Comment: Did you notice that your `switch` is equivalent to `del.tableRowNumber=indexPath.row`?

Comment: Literally just thought of that now! Just going to give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in order to implement a "straight" numeration (i.e. when the numbering of cells from section `n+1` continues after the cells from section `n`) you need to add the total number of rows in all preceding sections to the current row number.

If you know that the number of rows per section is one, you can take a shortcut to "straight" numeration, and use section number instead of the row number:

```
RecipeInfo *recipeInfo = recipeInfoArray[indexPath.section];
```

The exact formula with one row per section is `indexPath.section * 1 + indexPath.row`, but `indexPath.row` is always zero, and we can drop multiplication by 1. You should also use

```
del.tableRowNumber=indexPath.section;
```

in the replacement of your `switch` statement in the long press handler.

Comment: Theres only 1 row per section!

Comment: I'm guessing I can use the same code in my table view delegate - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath to load in the correct text at each row, rather than the text at the first element in the array to every cell?

Comment: @Lewis Yes, that's right. In fact, I was talking primarily about the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in the answer, because that's the most "visible" method of all. All other methods that deal with cell data need to follow the numbering scheme set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Thats great, thank you. Only reason I asked was it was working for the first part of the question and not the second - but I was forgetting to reload my table when returning back to the view ;)